# ng-repeat in template field in kendo grid columns

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I use kendo grid and use template for a cloumn like this below :

```
  {
        field: 'SwitchID',
        width: 100,
        title: 'cases',
        template: '<label ng-repeat=" item in  [1,2,3] " ><input type="radio" name="pageSet"  />{{item}}</label>'
    }
```

by doesn't work it and no rendered. when i inspect this see like this below :

Comment: Did you get the answer for this?